# Multi-channel square-wave noise removal

Tags: python, signal-processing, sensors, noise

I am new to the signals and Scipy but I may need to use it to remove the square-wave noise on multiple channels. I have tried a few things with fft but nothing seems to make sense so far. I am hoping to get a few clues here that I can try. Problem: I have a series of 6 sensors transmitting data via USB @ 1Hz (yes, very slow) / sensor. Every once in a while, they capture an external motor noise along with the signal that I am trying to remove (see attached figure). Any ideas on how to handle this? My original idea was to process the incoming data for 60 seconds, use fft to identify the common frequency on all the sensor channels and to remove it but that did not work. The code is basically useless to even share here.[the square wave in the figure is the noise I am trying to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtYIZ.png). Thank you for your input.

Comment: You say you've tried a few things - please share code of an attempt you expected to work and explain how it didn't and someone may be able to help you along.

Comment: Reproducible example could help